# JavaScript regex get + - * / after a number

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey I want to make a simple calculator. The calculator should do negatives and so I want to split my input string where I match a "+ - * /"

Input is for example "5+-3" so I want to match only the "+" because the "-" is part of my second number "-3"

The regex that I have at the moment is:

```
/(\+|-|\*|\)/
```

But this gives me the "
+" and "-"

Comment: Maybe `/([*\/]|\b[-+])/`? See https://regex101.com/r/z3KkOG/1

Comment: Great, I posted an answer below with an explanation. Please let know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/([*\/]|\b[-+])/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z3KkOG/1).

The `[*\/]|\b[-+]` pattern matches either

- `[*\/]` - a `*` or `/` char
- `|` - or
- `\b[-+]` - a `-` or `+` immediately preceded with a word char.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```js
/(?<=[0-9]+)[+\-*/](?=-?[0-9]+)/
```

- `(?<=[0-9]+)` is a "positive lookbehind": it means it checks that the expression between `(?<=` and `)` precedes the main expression but it is not matched. In this case we are checking that there is one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) before the operator
- `[+\-*/]` matches any of the four operators `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`
- `(?=-?[0-9]+)` is a "positive lookahead": it means it checks that the expression between `(?=` and `)` follows the main expression but it is not matched. In this case we are checking that there is an optional minus sign (`-?`) followed by one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) after the operator

**IMPORTANT**: some browsers might not support the the positive lookbehind feature

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing @Viktor's insight of using a word-boundary...

```
/\b[^.\d]/
```

- `\b` Immediately following an alphanumeric (which excludes +,-,/,*).
- `[^.\d]` Split on a single character that is not a period or decimal.